# Числовой палиндром

Tags: строки

Вводится последовательность символов. Точка - признак конца ввода. Общее число символов в последовательности может быть очень большим. Требуется составить минимальное по модулю число-палиндром максимальной длины, используя символы-цифры, входящие в последовательность, и вывести его на экран. Если это невозможно, то выдать специальное сообщение. Число не может начинаться с нуля за исключением самого числа ноль.
Я собрала в одну строку все числа из данной строки. Подскажите, как выделить минимальное число, повторяющееся два раза (нужно для составления палиндрома).
Язык программирования:Pascal

Comment: @Uchenitsa, на псевдокоде (паскаля не знаю)

   min = 9
   for i = 0; i < strlen; i++:
       if is_numeric(str[i]) && int(str[i]) < min:
           min = int(str[i])

Подразумевается, что в строке гарантированно есть цифры (поэтому можно смело использовать девятку)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Алгоритм таков:

1. идете по строке символов - `s[i]`. каждая итерация этого цикла определяет опорный символ относительно которого начинаете строить палиндром.
2. запускаете цикл по `j` (от 1), сравниваете `s[i-j]` с `s[i+j]` если они совпадают, значит палиндром существует. как только стали не равны палиндром кончился.
3. полученный на 2-м шаге палиндром запоминаете. если предыдущий палиндром был короче, затираете новым палиндромом. если предыдущий палиндром был такой же длины, но больше по модулю, опять же заменяете его на новый найденный.
4. в итоге получите самый длинный и самый маленький по модулю палиндром.

Замечания.

1. в п.2 необходимо предусмотреть, что палиндром может быть как нечетной длины так и четной. т.е. надо сравнивать и `s[i-j]` с `s[i+j]`, но и `s[i-j+1]` с `s[i+j]`.
2. если палиндром начинается и заканчивается нулем, обрезаете их.
3. не совсем понятно, является ли палиндромом число длины 1, учитывая замечание "за исключением самого числа 0". И как следствие как в таком случае может не быть палиндрома (только если вход пустой?).

**UPD**
Чтоб составить палиндром из любых введенных цифр, а не последовательности (как написано выше), заведите массив на 10 элементов, в котором храните количество цифр во входе, т.е. сколько было нулей, единиц, двоек... После того как прошли весь ввод, циклом смотрите количество каждой цифры (если больше 2-х) и конкатенируете с двух сторон. 11233211.
Максимальная цифра может быть нечетного количества.
Нули (если их больше 2-х) надо вставить после первой значащей цифры. 40055004.
Если четных цифр нет, значит берете минимальное, встретившееся хотя бы один раз, в т.ч. 0.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, спасибо за ваш ответ! Насколько я поняла условие задачи, палиндром должна составить сама программа, имея на входе набор каких-то чисел. Ваш вариант алгоритма - проверка существования палиндрома во входной последовательности.

Comment: @Uchenitsa, ага, понял, обновил ответ.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, спасибо! Особенно за __UPD__